# How can you link an HTML element to an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have a JavaScript object:

```
var foo = {
    // object content
};
```

And this object takes its data from an HTML element. Lets say this one:

```
<div id="linkDiv" data-url="www.google.com"></div>
```

Now, using jQuery you easily can add a direct link to the HTML element in the JavaScript object:

```
foo.divData = $('#linkDiv')
```

My question:

**The JavaScript object now has a reference to the HTML element. How can you add a reference to the JavaScript object to the HTML element?**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) function is for.

Setting:

```
$("#linkDiv").data("some-name-here", foo);
```

Getting later:

```
var anotherReferenceToFoo = $("#linkDiv").data("some-name-here");
```

Removing it:

```
$("#linkDiv").removeData("some-name-here");
```

`data` lets you associate any type of data with an HTML element, without causing circular reference problems (although those are really just an issue with really old versions of IE). The data can be of any type supported by JavaScript.

If you remove the element at some point, provided you remove it through jQuery rather than directly via the DOM, the data gets cleaned up (even if it's buried deep inside another element and you use `html` on that other element).

```js
var foo = {
  bar: "baz"
};

// Storing it
$("#linkDiv").data("some-name-here", foo);

// Retrieving it later
var f2 = $("#linkDiv").data("some-name-here");
snippet.log("f2.bar = " + f2.bar);

// Removing it
$("#linkDiv").removeData("some-name-here");

// Checking it's gone
var f3 = $("#linkDiv").data("some-name-here");
snippet.log(typeof f3); // undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div id="linkDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I already knew about the data method, but I didn't know you can also add references to objects that way.

Comment: @BasR.: Yup, anything you like. :-)